# Render subscript in using react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, subscript, react-markdown

I am unable to render subscript the markdown notation (`~this is subscript~but not this`) using `react-markdown`.

There are three ways I could easily find to render a do this: `remark-supersub`, `remark-sub-super` and something like this:

```
components={{ 
    em: ({ node, ...props }) => { 
            if ( props.children[0] && typeof props.children[0] === 'string' && props.children[0].startsWith('^')) { 
                    return <sup>{props.children[0].substring(1)}</sup> 
                } 
            if ( props.children[0] && typeof props.children[0] === 'string' && props.children[0].startsWith('~')) { 
                    return <sub>{props.children[0].substring(1)}</sub> 
                } 
            return <i {...props} /> 
            },
}}
```

... none of them works for me (they either do nothing or throw an error while rendering). Any other ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the packages you mentioned, [`remark-supersub`](https://npmjs.com/package/remark-supersub) works pretty well without much configuration.

You should pass this plugin as a `remarkPlugins` prop in the `Markdown` component:

```
import Markdown from "react-markdown";
import supersub from "remark-supersub";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
import remarkMath from "remark-math";

const markdown = `
# Markdown

21^st^ Century

H~2~O

~this is subscript~but not this

Something in ~~strikethrough~~
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Markdown
      remarkPlugins={[
        [remarkGfm, { singleTilde: false }],
        remarkMath,
        supersub,
      ]}
    >
      {markdown}
    </Markdown>
  );
}
```

This will render your markdown like this:

[image: Output image.]

[image: Edit React Markdown - Super/Sub]

---

Update: As seen in your comment, the issue lies with `remark-gfm` because this plugin will interpret by default `~text~` as strikethrough. The solution would be to pass `{ singleTilde: false }` to `remarkGfm`, that way you can keep a single `~text~` as subtext instead and `~~text~~` as strikethrough.

Comment: Ok, that works, but now I know where my original problem probably lies - once you combine remarkMath, remarkGfm with the superscript plugin (I need tables as well), it no longer works:

`import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'`
`import remarkMath from 'remark-math'`
`<Markdown remarkPlugins={[remarkMath, remarkGfm, supersub]}>{markdown}</Markdown>`

...this will display the subscript as strikethrough. Is there any way around it?

Comment: I updated my answer with something you could try. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works, thank you . Btw. the library could use better documentation, I had no idea you can add options like `singleTilde`.